# CNN-LSTM in Keras: Dimension Error

Tags: deep-learning, theano, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

In keras 1.2.2, I have made a dataset which has these dimensions:

- X_train: (2000, 100, 32, 32, 3)
- y_train: (2000,1)

Here, 2000 is the number of instances (batches of data), 100 is the number of samples in each batch, 32 is the image rows and cols, and 3 is the number of channels (RGB).

I have written this code which applies an LSTM after a CNN. I used TimeDistributed layers and took the average of the output of LSTM to have something like this:
[image]

I want LSTM to work on each batch, and then I take the average of the LSTM output on that batch. So, my total output (my labels) is a (2000,1) vector.

I get this error:

- Error when checking model target: expected lambda_14 to have 2
  dimensions, but got array with shape (2000L, 100L, 1L)

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import keras
from keras.layers import Input ,Dense, Dropout, Activation, LSTM
from keras.layers import Lambda, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling1D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K


import numpy as np

timesteps=100;
number_of_samples=2500;
nb_samples=number_of_samples;
frame_row=32;
frame_col=32;
channels=3;

nb_epoch=1;
batch_size=timesteps;

data= np.random.random((2500,timesteps,frame_row,frame_col,channels))
label=np.random.random((2500,timesteps,1))

X_train=data[0:2000,:]
y_train=label[0:2000]

X_test=data[2000:,:]
y_test=label[2000:,:]

#%%

model=Sequential();                          

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same'), input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512)))
#output dimension here is (None, 100, 512)                

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(35, name="first_dense" )))
#output dimension here is (None, 100, 35)                


model.add(LSTM(output_dim=20, return_sequences=True))
#output dimension here is (None, 100, 20)

time_distributed_merge_layer = Lambda(function=lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=False))

model.add(time_distributed_merge_layer)
#output dimension here is (None, 1, 20)


#model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(None,20)))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: I updated the code thanks to Nassim Ben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we follow the track of the shapes in your model, we get to `shape = (None, 100, 35)` after the `Dense()`. Then you feed that to an `LSTM()` which will return the whole sequence of hidden vectors of length 20 so you get a `shape = (None, 100, 20)`. Then you take the mean over the axis 1 so you get `shape = (None, 100, 1)`. 
There is something wrong with the architecture of that network because your targets have the `shape = (None, 1)`. So either change

```
LSTM(output_dim=20, return_sequences=False)
```

and add a `Flatten()` layer after the merge. Or `Flatten()` after the merge and use a `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` to get your predictions?

It depends on you but right now it cannot work.

Comment: Thanks alot :) The output shape of LSTM is shape = (None, 100, 20). The number of samples in my batch is 100 and I want to take average over those 100 outputs (of the LSTM) to get a 20 dimensional output. How can we do that here ?

Comment: Change the axis of the mean to 0 in your custom merge layer. To take the mean over the dimension of 100 values. Then Flatten to get a (None,20) shaped tensor. But this won't match your output since the labels you built have a shape of (None,100,1). Im not sure to understand what you really want to achieve here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed my code and updated it (in the question). Do you think that it is correct now? I have written the dimensions of tensors in the comments of the code. What I want to do is to first take average over the 100 (which is my batch), which results a 20-dim vector, and then apply a Dense over them to get a scalar output.

Comment: Are you sure the dimensions are correct? You didnt change the axis parameter for your mean. However, change your Label array to (2500,1) and round it (to get binary values instead of real values between 0 and 1

Comment: you are right. should I write like this : time_distributed_merge_layer = Lambda(function=lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=0, keepdims=False)
, output_shape=(None, 20))

Comment: axis is 0 to have the mean over those 100 (the whole batch), and the output_shape should be (None,20) so that I use a Dense and make it (None, 1). Is it right ?